# Navigate from SwiftUI List to UIKit storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, uikit, swiftui-list

I am playing around with SwiftUI. Currently, I have an app with storyboards, few SwiftUI views, but end views.

Now I am struggling with navigating from SwiftUI to UIKit views.

```
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("App Settings")) {
                    ForEach(AppSettings.allCases) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: item.navigator) {
                            SettingsRow(title: item.title, description: item.description, imageName: item.imageName)
                        }
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.grayscaleGray3.swiftUIValue)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Reminders")) {
                    ForEach(SettingsReminders.allCases) { item in
                        SettingsRow(title: item.title, description: item.description, imageName: item.imageName)
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.grayscaleGray3.swiftUIValue)
                }
                Section(header: Text("About us")) {
                    ForEach(AboutUs.allCases) { item in
                        SettingsRow(title: item.title, description: item.description, imageName: item.imageName)
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.grayscaleGray3.swiftUIValue)
                }
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                
            }
        }
```

The problem is with NavigationLink(destination: item.navigator)... How do I navigate to a UIKit view like that? Or is there another way to do so? Settings will have 3-4 sections, with 4-6 rows in a section. Any help?

Comment: Have you checked out https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit? You can wrap UIKit `UIView`s and `UIViewControllers` in representable objects that you can display in a SwiftUI view hierarchy

Comment: @jnpdx I have seen this. But does that mean that every UIKit view will need to be modified for now? Is that the only solution? :/

Comment: Not modified as such, but you will need to wrap them in a representable class

Answer (score 1):

are you wrapping swiftui inside uikit views?

something like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: SwiftUIView())

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        addChild(hostingController)
        view.addSubview(hostingController.view)
        NSLayoutConstraints.activate(your constraint code)
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("App Settings")) {
                    ForEach(AppSettings.allCases) { item in
                        NavigationLink(destination: item.navigator) {
                            SettingsRow(title: item.title, description: item.description, imageName: item.imageName)
                        }
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.grayscaleGray3.swiftUIValue)
                }
                Section(header: Text("Reminders")) {
                    ForEach(SettingsReminders.allCases) { item in
                        SettingsRow(title: item.title, description: item.description, imageName: item.imageName)
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.grayscaleGray3.swiftUIValue)
                }
                Section(header: Text("About us")) {
                    ForEach(AboutUs.allCases) { item in
                        SettingsRow(title: item.title, description: item.description, imageName: item.imageName)
                    }.listRowBackground(Color.grayscaleGray3.swiftUIValue)
                }
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                
            }
        }
}
```

If what you have is something remotely similar to the code above then I assume the reason to why the navigation does not work is that you are using the NavigationView as opposed to the UINavigationController of your Viewcontroller class.

what I would do in this case is to create a view model that can get Events from the swiftui view and send messages to the UIViewController

something like

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
     @ObservedObject private let viewModel: MyViewModel

     init(vm: MyViewModel) {
         self.viewModel = vm
     }

     enum PresenterEvent {
        case navigateToAnotherViewController
    }
    /* View Code */
}
```

inside viewModel you can have a function
something like

```
class MyViewModel {
    func handleSwiftUIViewEvent(_ event: SwiftUIView.PresenterEvent) {
          // try to communicate with the view controller based on the event
         // then have the view controller to navigate to the desired view controller
    }
}
```

I wrote all this off the top of my head so please let me know if something is not clear or I missed anything